# mysql summary values in cols with same specific col

Tags: mysql

I have a table like below

```
+----+---------+-------+-----+----------+
| id | user_id | price | qty | category |
+----+---------+-------+-----+----------+
```

and I have a query to database

```
SELECT *,(SELECT `login` FROM `users` WHERE `users`.`user_id`=`warehouse`.`user_id`) AS `login`, (`price`*`qty`) AS `total_price` FROM `warehouse`
```

So what I need... I need next col with sumary of total price, where rows are same category

**edit**

**Tables sample**

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `warehouse` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
  `user_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `price` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `qty` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `category` int(11) DEFAULT NULL
);

INSERT INTO `warehouse` (`id`, `user_id`, `price`, `qty`, `category`) VALUES
(1, 1, 10, 5, 1),
(2, 1, 15, 2, 1),
(3, 1, 8, 3, 1),
(4, 1, 28, 10, 1),
(5, 1, 10, 1, 2);

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `users` (
  `user_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `login` varchar(32) DEFAULT NULL
);

INSERT INTO `users` (`user_id`, `login`) VALUES
(1, 'test');
```

**Results with my query**

```
+----+---------+-------+-----+----------+-------+-------------+
| id | user_id | price | qty | category | login | total_price |
+----+---------+-------+-----+----------+-------+-------------+
| 1  | 1       | 10    | 5   | 1        | test  | 50          |
+----+---------+-------+-----+----------+-------+-------------+
| 2  | 1       | 15    | 2   | 1        | test  | 30          |
+----+---------+-------+-----+----------+-------+-------------+
| 3  | 1       | 8     | 3   | 1        | test  | 24          |
+----+---------+-------+-----+----------+-------+-------------+
| 4  | 1       | 28    | 10  | 2        | test  | 280         |
+----+---------+-------+-----+----------+-------+-------------+
| 5  | 1       | 10    | 1   | 1        | test  | 10          |
+----+---------+-------+-----+----------+-------+-------------+
```

**What I need**

```
+----+---------+-------+-----+----------+-------+-------------+--------------------------+
| id | user_id | price | qty | category | login | total_price | sum_category_total_price |
+----+---------+-------+-----+----------+-------+-------------+--------------------------+
| 1  | 1       | 10    | 5   | 1        | test  | 50          | 114                      |
+----+---------+-------+-----+----------+-------+-------------+--------------------------+
| 2  | 1       | 15    | 2   | 1        | test  | 30          | 114                      |
+----+---------+-------+-----+----------+-------+-------------+--------------------------+
| 3  | 1       | 8     | 3   | 1        | test  | 24          | 114                      |
+----+---------+-------+-----+----------+-------+-------------+--------------------------+
| 4  | 1       | 28    | 10  | 2        | test  | 280         | 280                      |
+----+---------+-------+-----+----------+-------+-------------+--------------------------+
| 5  | 1       | 10    | 1   | 1        | test  | 10          | 114                      |
+----+---------+-------+-----+----------+-------+-------------+--------------------------+
```

Comment: That is not `MySQL` syntax as you tagged the question. It looks like `sql-server`. Please correct the tag.

Comment: I edited syntax to MySQL, sorry

Comment: Can you add some sample data and the expected result?

Comment: @Jens: added sample tables and expected results

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that should solve your problem:

```
SELECT *,(SELECT `login` FROM `users` WHERE `users`.`user_id`=`warehouse`.`user_id`) AS `login`, (`price`*`qty`) AS `total_price` 
FROM warehouse join (select category, sum((`price`*`qty`)) AS `total_price` from warehouse group by category) as totals on warehouse.category=totals.category
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select *,(price*qty) AS total_price from Warehouse
join (select category,sum(price*qty) as sum_category_total_price from Warehouse group by category) as Temp 
on Temp.category=Warehouse.category
join users 
on users.user_id=warehouse.user_id
```

[DEMO](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/54f9cf/1)

Comment: This is no what I needed, I need summary of total_price, where is the same category... in your demo is these values 50+200=250